# Tax on foreign income paid the year after

Tags: income-tax, canada, foreign-income

I was a self employee and worked for company in Oct 2017 in France, but only received the salary the year after, Jan 2018. It was my only foreign income.

I didn't count it for 2017 as I thought I only had to report money I received in 2017. So should this income be reported for 2018 tax (because I received it in 2018)?

Comment: It seems weird to ask that question.... Shouldn't you have been sure that you had to report it this year before choosing not to report it last year ?

Comment: @xyious yeah sorry :p I think I convinced myself that I didn't had to report it for 2017 since I didn't have the money in 2017, but I recently discussed with someone who said I should have reported it when I 'earned' it in 2017. So the question would have been more of "should I amend 2017 or report it 2018?"

Comment: In the US you have to report the income when you get paid. Which means if you get paid biweekly and the payday is the last day of the year you have technically earned more money than you got paid. Regardless you report the money you got paid that year. I would be surprised if the rules are different in different countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fairly straightforward. You received income in 2018 and you have to pay income tax on income received in 2018. So the answer should be yes.